# Silverlight C# Game or Graphics Engine?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Are there any good C# Silverlight Graphics or Game engines currently? I am planning to create a game with it (either 2d or 3d) but are there already usable frameworks or should I expect to have to build everything myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the moment, probably the most well known graphics engine is:

[Balder](http://www.codeplex.com/Balder)

> Managed GameEngine with both 2D and 3D
>   support targetting Silverlight 2/3,
>   Xna and OpenGL.

There is also:

[Kit3D](http://www.codeplex.com/Kit3D)

> Kit3D is a 3D graphics engine for
>   Microsoft Silverlight.

As far as *Game Engines* go, there is:

[PlayBits Engine](http://www.envygames.com/content/index.php/playbits-engine)
Although PlayBits is not yet available, and will not be free.

Answer (score 2):

If you're targeting both XNA and Silverlight for 2D games you can use the SilverSprite library at http://silversprite.codeplex.com and it may also be useful if you're used to a traditional game loop and draw calls.

Answer (score 1):

For simple games it is fairly easy to make you own game Silverlight game engine. This tutorial [here](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/blog/archive/2009/09/03/silverlight-game-programming-tutorials.aspx) shows you how to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most enhanced 3D engine for Silverlight so far is [Silvermotion](http://postvision.net/SilverMotion/Demos.aspx)

It has some quite impressive demos and looks more like a high tech DirectX engine than the usual stuff and runs quite well.